# Sorting @FetchRequest (not dynamically) with SwiftUI

Tags: swift, xcode, core-data, swiftui, fetchrequest

I tried the entire day to find the simplest solution to sort a @FetchRequest without any success!

I have tried this little modification:

```
@AppStorage("sortTitle") private var sortTitle = true

@Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext
@FetchRequest(sortDescriptors: [ sortTitle ? SortDescriptor(\.title) : SortDescriptor(\.date) ]) private var items: FetchedResults<Item>
```

And of course it doesn't work. Actually, I'm looking for something very simple because this isn't a dynamic sorting ; it's more like a one-time sorting that can be done by toggling `sortTitle` from the Settings screen.

There's of course one online solution (on the link below) but I'm not good enough to understand it correctly at the moment!
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O4043RVjCGU

Thanks, in advance, for your feedback. :)

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/wwdc21/10017

Comment: Thanks @loremipsum for your comment. I can clearly see that this might be the best way to sort a FetchRequest (recommended by Apple). Unfortunately, I'm not able to convert the example to my case, this is out of my reach (development level). But thanks again for the link. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is worth a shot but to be honest `@FetchRequest` seems to be designed for a a ContentView that is only init once which is not the way SwiftUI is supposed to work.

```
.onAppear {
    items.sortDescriptors = sortTitle ? [SortDescriptor(\.title)] : [SortDescriptor(\.date)]
}
.onChange(of: sortTitle) { newSortTitle in
    items.sortDescriptors = sortTitle ?  [SortDescriptor(\.title)] : [SortDescriptor(\.date)]
}
```

The flaw is that if the View containing this code is re-init, the change made to the sortDescriptors is lost.

Comment: Thanks @malhal for this solution. I tried it and it works like a charm! I just had to add `:of` for `.onChange(of: sortTitle)` and the model name before `.title` and `.date`. But I'm wondering something: you're trying to tell me that this solution isn't the best and can cause some problems? What problems? Thanks again!

Comment: if the View containing the @FetchRequest is re-init, the change made to the sortDescriptors is lost.

Comment: What do you mean by a "re-init"?

Comment: var body some View { FetchView() }